# Botframework DirectLineClient.Conversations.PostActivityAsync returns null

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm trying to send an activity through DirectLineClient library to my bot :

```
        var directLineClient = new DirectLineClient($"{secret}");
        directLineClient.BaseUri = new Uri($"https://directline.botframework.com/");

        var conversation = await directLineClient.Conversations.StartConversationAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var activity = new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine.Activity();
        activity.From = new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine.ChannelAccount();
        activity.From.Name = "Morgan";
        activity.Text = message;
        activity.Type = "message";

        var resourceResponse = await directLineClient.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(conversation.ConversationId, activity).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await ReadBotMessagesAsync(directLineClient, conversation.ConversationId);
```

resourceResponse is always null.

***Edit after Nicolas R answer***

I added a method to wait for a response from the bot :

```
    private static async Task ReadBotMessagesAsync(DirectLineClient client, string conversationId)
    {
        string watermark = null;

        while (true)
        {
            var activitySet = await client.Conversations.GetActivitiesAsync(conversationId, watermark);
            watermark = activitySet?.Watermark;

            foreach (Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine.Activity activity in activitySet.Activities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(activity.Text);

                if (activity.Attachments != null)
                {
                    foreach (Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine.Attachment attachment in activity.Attachments)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(attachment.ContentType);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (activitySet.Activities.Count > 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

But I never get out of ReadBotMessagesAsync.

I precise that I can communicate with my bot through HTTP request (tested with Postman), and it should be sending a response message whenever a message is sent.

Comment: I'm having the same problem --- either PostActivityAsync is not sending out information or GetActivitiesAsync is not retrieving any information? What is your solution in the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edited after OP precision*

### Methods always returns null

Based on the documentation/samples, it looks like this `PostActivityAsync` return is never used so the value may not be relevant.

From the samples:

```
await client.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(conversation.ConversationId, userMessage);
```

See example [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/v3-sdk-samples/CSharp/core-DirectLine/README.md).

For those who want more details, because this answer is only limited to the comparison with the sample use, this package is sadly not open-source: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2756

### Remarks (for those who would be using the wrong packages)

I would not recommend to use this `DirectLineClient` Nuget package located here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DirectLineClient as it is not maintained since May 2016 and the Bot Framework has changed a lot since that time.

Moreover, it is using DirectLine API 1.0, which is not the best practice at the time. See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-1-1-concepts?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=azure-bot-service-3.0):

> **Important**
>
> This article introduces key concepts in Direct Line API 1.1 and
> provides information about relevant developer resources. If you are
> creating a new connection between your client application and bot, **use
> Direct Line API 3.0 instead**.

Comment: Are you sure about that ? I'm using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine

Comment: That's not the package I mentioned. It is okay with yours, I made an edit. I will have a look to your code soon. Can you add more details about this implementation?

Comment: I tried to get activities from my bot using the same method as the sample you provide. I'm going to update my question

Comment: What do you have on your bot side when you receive a message? Are you doing something like an echo?

Comment: Yes, I return a message depending on what the user inputs. In this example, it should send "Error command"

Comment: Anyway, I accept your answer, it doesn't solve my problem but my question was not precise enough

Comment: Found the solution... I never should have set BaseUri, now it works !

Comment: @Morgan - I am running into the same issue. Read isn't working for me. Can you please share your final solution?

Comment: @Sornakumar From what I remember and my last comment, when I removed " directLineClient.BaseUri = new Uri($"https://directline.botframework.com/");" it worked.

Comment: Thanks. I was passing `From.Name` as `null` and that was causing the issue. Changed that to a string and it fixed it for me.